# Force emulator functions URL when having two projects in the same account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

- I am using Firebase Emulator in a WEB project.
- I have two projects in my account: `plony` and `prod--plony`.
- Until now, when I run the emulator using the CLI, my functions' URLs ended up like this: 
  `http://localhost:5001/plony/us-central1/{{FUNCTIONNAME}}`
- From now (I'm not sure why) - when I run the emulator the address template has changed: 
  `http://localhost:5001/prod--plony/us-central1/{{FUNCTIONNAME}}`
- According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#web-version-8), the template should as following: `http://$HOST:$PORT/$PROJECT/$REGION/$NAME` . 
  Which means somehow my `$PROJECT` var has changed.
- I tried to look all over my repo for `prod--plony` and still can't find this phrase anywhere locally. Not in:
- `.env`
- `.runtimeconfig.json`
- `.firebaserc`
- `firebase.json`

  And not anywhere else! I also tried to switch the firebase project before starting the emulator: `firebase use plony`. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add `--project=plony` when running `firebase emulators:start` so overall: 
`firebase emulators:start --project=plony`